Generate Downloadable PDF
Tech Stack:
Node.js(nest.js),
Docker,
GCP - Cloud Run,
NPM:
Chromium: Latest
NPM:(Tried with both puppeteer version)
"puppeteer": "13.5.0" :
Issue:
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
"puppeteer": "22.7.1"
Issue:
Could not find Chrome (ver. 124.0.6367.78). This can occur if either . 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/node/.cache/puppeteer).
Here is my Dockerfile(part which includes chromium installation)
Dockerfile
# Build
FROM node:20-alpine AS build

# Installs latest Chromium package.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont

RUN ls -l /usr/bin/chromium

WORKDIR /Project/api
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true"
COPY package*.json  ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

index.js(launching chrome)
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: puppeteer.executablePath(),
        args: ['no-sandbox', 'disable-setuid-sandbox']
   });

By this able to generate pdf on local successfully, issue on cloud run.
Any help would be appreciated
